# issue in Number generation in Sequence using Cache

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a sequence created with `nocycle`, `noorder`, `cache 100` and `increment by 1`. I am using the below SQL to generate sequence:

```
select myseq.nextVal from dual;
```

With this sequence I got values between `206764957` and `206765478` on one day. After few days when I used this process again it gave me values between `206765361` and `206793474`.

So in my first run the highest number was `206765478` and in my second run the lowest number was `206765361`. I was expecting all of the numbers to in the second run to be higher than ll of the numbers from the first run, not to have them overlapping.

Could you please help in finding the issue with this sequence?

Comment: Are you sure which rows came from each run - how can you tell, from another column, e.g. a timestamp, which can't have been modified since? If you are sure, could anyone have modified the sequence in between?

Comment: I am sure, no one is modified in between and also sure about the seq which got generated with each run.

Comment: Are the runs using fresh database connections, or pooled connection(s) that were alive across both runs? Were any individual numbers duplicated, or did you just see 100-blocks interleaved by the runs? Are you using RAC (each node can have it's own cache, but won't overlap)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation:

> **ORDER**
>   Specify ORDER to guarantee that sequence numbers are generated in order of request. This clause is useful if you are using the sequence numbers as timestamps. Guaranteeing order is usually not important for sequences used to generate primary keys.
>
> ORDER is necessary only to guarantee ordered generation if you are using Oracle Real Application Clusters. If you are using exclusive mode, then sequence numbers are always generated in order.
>
> **NOORDER**
>   Specify NOORDER if you do not want to guarantee sequence numbers are generated in order of request. This is the default.

You have specified `noorder` so sequences numbers are not guaranteed to be generated in the order of the request. From the behaviour you are seeing, and assuming your assertion that the sequence hasn't been modified is true, you seem to be using RAC and are seeing the effect of the way caching is implemented across RAC nodes.

And from the [Real Application Clusters Administration and Deployment Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/rac.112/e41960/design.htm#RACAD7387):

> If you use sequence numbers, then always use CACHE with the NOORDER option for optimal performance in sequence number generation. With the CACHE option, however, you may have gaps in the sequence numbers. If your environment cannot tolerate sequence number gaps, then use the NOCACHE option or consider pre-generating the sequence numbers. If your application requires sequence number ordering but can tolerate gaps, then use CACHE and ORDER to cache and order sequence numbers in Oracle RAC. If your application requires ordered sequence numbers without gaps, then use NOCACHE and ORDER. The NOCACHE and ORDER combination has the most negative effect on performance compared to other caching and ordering combinations.

If you are trying to use the sequence to show the order that rows were created then you could use `order` but that [will slow things down](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:369390500346406705#2767396300346520884). It might be more reliable to use a timestamp column, though that is limited by the precision supported by your operating system, and might not be unique.

Comment: working in parallel and also having 3 nodes. But my understanding over here is: in any case latest run min number got generated should be greater than max number got generated in last run. That is not happening for some reason here and looking for a root cause for this.

Comment: @VenkataRamireddyCH - well, your understanding seems to be wrong. Each RAC node has its own cache and the order is not guaranteed. It's behaving as it should with the sequence you've defined. If all of your runs always hit the same node exclusively then what you expect would probably still happen; as soon as you hit a second node you have a separate cache. From that AskTom page I linked to: 'do not rely on sequences being a) gap free b) sequential c) always increasing. Only think of them as "unique - nothing more, nothing less'.

Comment: even if it is having different cache, the sequence it is getting generated should not have jumbled order. right?  Here in my case, on one node the numbers got generated are: 1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 10, 11, 15, etc.. and in my 2nd run it gave me 3,5,7,8,12,13,14,16, etc.. Is this behavior expected?

Comment: @VenkataRamireddyCH - yes it should. That's what `noorder' means.

Comment: I understand the concept here. Thank you all for all your suggestions and support.