# Is there any chance that a oracle sequence may generate a value less than the latest generated value

Tags: oracle, sequence-generators

I have a sequence generator in oracle .

cache-size 1000
INCREMENT_BY 1

I faced a issue wherein the latest value generated by the sequence was less than the prev latest

consider two columns with ID and created-date

1. 490206        4/25/2019  3:02:15 PM
2. 492204        4/24/2019  10:09:21 PM
3. 492202        4/24/2019  3:57:55 PM

As in the above example my latest entry in table is 490206 which is lesser than previous latest 492204.

Can this happen in oracle sequence generator? How to fix this?

Comment: Are you using RAC?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39832607/266304) if you are. Or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4866959/266304) might give some useful background.

Answer (score 0):

We have experienced this sort of trouble previously when a developer was inserting into a table with a sequence but was calculating the next sequence number instead of using the sequence.nextval to increment.