# Oracle "generated always as identity" gives 21 as sequence value

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence

Oracle sequence is giving 21 instead of 3. I don't know why 21 but not other values. Please help to understand this.

**Update**
I used this sequence for static reference table so that id can be used for java code to pull data which should be in order from 1 ,1+1,1+2 and so on.

```
create table table1 (id number(20) generated always as identity, name varchar2(20)); 
insert into table1(name) values('111');
insert into table1(name) values('222');
select * from table1;
--Output
1   111
2   222
insert into table1(name) values('333');
select * from table1;
21  333 -- problamatic id as 21 generated
1   111
2   222
```

Comment: By default sequences are cached (for good reasons) and not ordered, and various things can cause gaps (e.g. rollback); and if you're using RAC then each node has its own cache, so you can get interleaved values. That's normal. Sequences aren't supposed to be gapless or necessarily time-ordered (your next insert might now get 3 even though 21 exists). If you need to know the order the inserts happened then [you can make it ordered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39833854/266304), or a timestamp column might work better. But it depends why you think it's problematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identity column is *in the background* based on a sequence value. Sequences guarantee uniqueness, but values they return aren't / don't have to be gapless.

Why do you feel that `21` is "problematic" value? What's wrong with it? It is as good as any other value.

If you want to return gapless values **during `select`**, then include e.g. `row_number` analytic function:

```
select row_number() over (order by id) rn,      --> this
       name
from table1;
```

and present it to users. Leave `ID` for your own purposes, when you have to access rows by it. End users don't care about ID anyway.

---

You commented that you

> wanted to get values in sequence but which is not happening

"I want" doesn't help much. **Why** do you want it? What benefit do you expect?

There is a way to create gapless sequence of numbers, but (as far as I can tell) it requires some programming.

Also, there's an issue when you **delete** a row, somewhere in the middle of that sequence. What then? You'll again get a gap. Will you resequence all numbers? You could (theoretically), but - what if there are foreign keys that reference that ID? Modifying primary key values is rarely a good idea.

Shortly: don't do any of that. Accept that sequence will be unique with possible gaps and move on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i wanted to get values in sequence but which is not happening.